# Can't visualize the dropout layer in model summary using this method

Tags: keras, model, summary, dropout

```
n_col = X_tr_ss.shape[1]
n_out = y_tr_ss.shape[1]
com_name = 'mlp'

dn_lyr = [256, 128]
drp_out = [0.2]
actv_name = ['relu','relu']

n_patience = 5
n_epoch = 300

nd_lyr = len(dn_lyr)
in_lyr = k.layers.Input(shape=(n_col,), name = 'inpt_'+com_name)
re_lyr = k.layers.Dense(dn_lyr[0],activation=actv_name[0], name = 'hidden_1_'+com_name)(in_lyr)
dp_lyr = k.layers.Dropout(drp_out[0])(re_lyr)

if nd_lyr > 1:
    dn_lyn = dn_lyr[1:]
    ac_nm = actv_name[1:]
    for i_lyr, nd in enumerate(dn_lyn):
        re_lyr = k.layers.Dense(nd, activation=ac_nm[i_lyr], name = 'hidden_'+str(i_lyr+2)+ '_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
out_lyr = k.layers.Dense(n_out, name = 'out_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
model_mlp = k.models.Model(in_lyr,out_lyr)

model_mlp.summary()
```

Model: "model_9"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

inpt_mlp (InputLayer)        (None, 189)               0

---

hidden_1_mlp (Dense)         (None, 256)               48640

---

hidden_2_mlp (Dense)         (None, 128)               32896

---

## out_mlp (Dense)              (None, 10554)             1361466

Total params: 1,443,002
Trainable params: 1,443,002
Non-trainable params: 0

As seen above the "drop out" layer is not seen in model summary.

Comment: Can you add [mre]?